# Table Data Type Alter

Tags: mysql, database

I created a table named items and inserted name as int and provided the length as 255 type by mistake but now i wanted to alter the table structure and run the query as--

ALTER TABLE items
ALTER COLUMN name varchar(255); but it is not altering the table what i need to change in the table.help plz

Answer (score 22, accepted):

there are two ways

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE <column_name> <column_name> <type>
```

**note:** you have to write column name twice
OR

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY <column_name> <type> ;
```

#### [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: bro..just tell me how do i vote its says u need 15 credits to vote

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
alter table t1 modify column name varchar(255);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ALTER table items
MODIFY name varchar(255);
```