# Change datatype mysql

Tags: mysql

I try all of this options:
[Table Data Type Alter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148979/table-data-type-alter)

And this is the output:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Xarxa CHANGE codiXarxa codiXarxa INT;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './monxar/#sql-969_5b' to './monxar/Xarxa' (errno: 150)

mysql> ALTER TABLE Xarxa CHANGE codiXarxa codiXarxa INT(3);
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './monxar/#sql-969_5b' to './monxar/Xarxa' (errno: 150)

mysql> ALTER TABLE Xarxa MODIFY COLUMN codiXarxa codiXarxa INT(3);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'codiXarxa INT(3)' at line 1

mysql> alter table Xarxa modify codiXarxa int(3);
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './monxar/#sql-969_5b' to './monxar/Xarxa' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Can't create table (errno: 150)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Comment: There is probably a foreign key constraint between this table and another one, and by modifying it you are creating a data type mismatch between them.  Look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE Xarxa` to see existing key relationships.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Xarxa MODIFY codiXarxa INTEGER;
```

But it looks like errors you get are foreign key errors.
If I'm right... drop foreign key first and than modify data type.

```
ALTER TABLE Xarxa DROP FOREIGN KEY codiXarxa;
ALTER TABLE Xarxa MODIFY codiXarxa INTEGER;
```